# Poner div al final de otro div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy tratando de colocar el div rojo justo en la parte inferior del verde, sin afectar a los demás elementos que se encuentra precisamente dentro de este div verde (Home,Reportes,Mi Perfil), pero no lo logro, alguna idea aquí esta el código:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
.menu{
    background-color: green;
    border-right: 1px rgb(218, 218, 218) solid;
    border-bottom: 1px rgb(218, 218, 218) solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 95vh;
}
.menu_opts{
    height: 70px;
    width: 180px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #a5a5a59f;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: blue;
    /* transition-duration: 300ms; */
}

<div class="row">
        <div class="menu">
                <div class="menu_opts" id="home">
                        <li class="bi bi-house-fill"> Home </li>
                        </div>

                <div class="menu_opts" id="reports">
                    <li class="bi bi-megaphone-fill"> Reportes </li>
                </div>

                <div class="menu_opts" id="profile">
                    <li class="bi bi-people-fill"> Mi Perfil </li>
                </div>
                <div class="sb">
                    <div class="menu_opts" id="log_out">
                        <li class="bi bi-box-arrow-left"> Salir </li>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a SOes. El código no debería estar en imágenes, recuerda que no todos podemos verlo... por favor, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/559501/edit) tu pregunta y pon el código en su respectivo formato. *"Estoy tratando de colocar el div rojo justo en la parte inferior del verde"* Y cual es el verde que dices?

Comment: Cuál es el div verde? Yo no veo ninguno?

Comment: Bienvenido. Por favor, carga el codigo de la imagen como codigo para que los colaboradores de Stackoverflow puedan ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, la publicación ya fue actualizada con la informacion mas estructurada. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo!, lo logre solucionar de la siguiente manera:

```
.menu{
    /* background-color: green; */
    border-right: 1px rgb(218, 218, 218) solid;
    border-bottom: 1px rgb(218, 218, 218) solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 95vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
}
.menu > .sd{
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

Agrege un `margin-top: auto` apuntado el .menu (que seria el div verde) con el .sd (que seria el div rojo) y agregando al .menu :

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

Aquí el resultado:
[image: Resultado]